# 32-bit error with Dota 2 Steam Web API

Tags: 32bit-64bit, 32-bit, steam, steam-web-api

This concerns the following request:

```
https://api.steampowered.com/IDOTA2Match_570/GetMatchHistory/V001/?key=<MY KEY>&account_id=<MY ID>
```

The response I received looks like this:

```
 ...

"players":[
    {
        "account_id": 4294967295
        ...
    },
    {
        "account_id": 4294967295
        ...
    }

 ...
```

`account_id` is supposed to return the user's 32-bit account ID (documentation [here](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/WebAPI/GetMatchHistory)). A handful of them contain valid IDs but a large amount of them say `4294967295`. Since `4294967295` was showing up so much, I assumed it was the result of an error so I googled it and found this from Wikipedia:

> The number 4,294,967,295, equivalent to the hexadecimal value FFFF,FFFF16, is the maximum value for a 32-bit unsigned integer in computing.

Does this mean it's an error on Steam's side? Is this API bugged and unusable? Is there any way I can remedy this?

Comment: Can't say API is unstable but you can't do much to remedy account_id , you can either accept the response as valid data and proceed or raise an error or exception. The only thing you can do is raise this with their tech support

Answer (score 6):

I know it is too late to answer this question, but if anyone still wonders and want to know why the **Steam DOTA 2 API** is returning the same number `4294967295`for many `IDs`.

There is nothing wrong with the **Steam DOTA 2 API** nor it is bugged. If you see this with many `IDs`it is perfectly normal.

The reason behind this is because your **Account ID** in Steam is **32-bit Unsigned INT.**
And if you are using DOTA 2 API to get match history of the player He/She must have enabled **EXPOSE MATCH DATA TO PUBLIC** option from Dota 2 Client(Inside the Setting option In-game). It is disabled by default.

So, if the user has not enabled that option yet, and if you try to access the Match Data of that user, the API will return status as Negative. As the Steam ID is 32 bit it will return **MAXINT (2^32-1 or 4294967295)**. As a result you are getting that same number ID in many case in which user has not exposed the data publicly.

The solution is either user expose the data or whenever you see that ID don't store in Database considering as Real Account, give it a name something like Anonymous or as per your choice.